# user specific roles with aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Can one use Amazon Cognito to grant temporary access token/keys/etc in order to use a mobile app or website to call S3 functions?

i want non-iam users to be able to login, be authenticated and then have access to their specific folder in a particular S3 bucket.

Cognito seems to only let me use the identityId as the prefix, but that isn't the same id for each user every time, unless i'm mistaken.

i started from their pet-store-lambda example, and extended it to provided S3 access based on their identityId, but i logged in with the same user on the 2nd day and got a totally different identityId...

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The link below might be helpful.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-cognito

One other thing to consider using is a signed url or cookie with aws cloud front.  I used this on a side project and it worked out well.  It allows you to put a cloud front url in front of a private s3 bucket and only allows access if they have a proper signed url.  You can do things like set time limits as well.  I don't know if that works with cognito off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito Identity returns the same identity id for same authenticated user everytime, so this should not have happened.
Seems like logins map was not correctly set while making calls to Cognito, as a result of that Cognito will treat it as unauth user and when the Identity Id is cleared from device cache it will end up vending a new identity id.

Comment: thanks, i might have been mistaken on it. i will keep an eye on it, it easily could have been a bug on my end... thanks.